# margin, padding not working in my case

Tags: html, css

i couldnt move div content up. tried padding, margin. could u pls tel me where the problem is?
here, the sample code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <HEAD>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <style>
            .line1
            { 
               background-color:#AAAAAA;
               height: 100%;
               width: 1px;
               display: inline-block;
            } 
            .line2
            { 
               background-color:#CE5611;
               height: 100%;
               width: 1px;
               display: inline-block;
               margin-left: 121px;
            } 
        </style>
    </HEAD> 
    <body>
        <div id="a1" style='padding-left: 14px;width: 400px; height:148px'>
            <span style='display: inline-block'>
                <div>
                    <div>h1.1</div>
                    <div>h1.2</div>
                    <div>h1.3</div>
                    <div>h1.4</div>
                    <div>h1.5</div>
                    <div>h1.6</div>
                    <div>h1.7</div>
                </div>
            </span>
            <span class="line1"></span>
            <span style='display: inline-block'>
                <div>h2.1</div>
                <div>h2.2</div>
                <div>h2.3</div>
                <div>h2.4</div>
            </span>
            <span class="line2"></span>
            <span style='display: inline-block'>
                <div>h3.1</div>
                <div>h3.2</div>
                <div>h3.3</div>
                <div>h3.4</div>
            </span>
            <span class="line1"></span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what div of all? explain us further what you want to achieve

Comment: why are keeping divs inside span, it should be opposite , spans are used inbetween divs to provide inline....text or images etc. use block elements...to do any margin ,padding stuff

Comment: Not sure what you want but there are some errors in you're code. According to your Doctype 1) the HEAD element must be lowercase 2) A Div can't be a child of a Span

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for `vertical-align:top;` ?

Comment: do you think his html layout is good,i think its wrong...espicially div blocks inside span...s what do you say

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your problem, but a generic solution to all similar problems. Install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) in your firefox and inspect all elements to see which one is the problematic. It displays margins and paddings over the selected elements so that you can quickly detect it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the layout.

Don't try to give divs inside a span, thats not a good approach.

what are h2.1 , h2.2

if you want lists to show , show UL or OL , orderred lists or undered lists..